# Vuejs - How to get all unique values in a array (remove duplicates) using v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

How to show only one button per every **distinct** `date` ?

can i use two v-for loops ? how to select **distinct** values in my loop?

```
<div v-for="question in allQuestions" >
  <button v-for="date in question.date">
    {{date}}
  </button>
</div>
```

#### Data model :

```
allQuestions : []
question : {'id' : '123' , 'date' : '25'}
```

Comment: yes you can use two loops like you did, but your object should be inside your array within array. like: 
`allQuestions : [
    question : {'id' : '123' , [{'date' : '25'},{'date' : '25'},{'date' : '27'}]},
]
`

Comment: @Najamussaqib **distinct** values

Comment: you can select or bind the value like this. 
`<button v-for="date in question.date">
    {{date.id}}
  </button>`

Comment: @Najamussaqib doesn't work. because data don't have an id attribute.

Comment: this is because your `allQuestions` array have nothing in it. put your `question` object inside your `allQuestion` array.

Comment: you data should look like this.:
`allQuestions = [
    {
      question : [
      {'id' : '1' , 'date' : '25'},
      {'id' : '2' , 'date' : '26'},
      {'id' : '3' , 'date' : '27'}
      ]
    }
    ]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

> The `Set` object lets you store **unique** values of any type, whether primitive values or object references.

MDN's example:

```js
const numbers = [2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 32, 3, 4, 5]

console.log([...new Set(numbers)])
```

Just modify it to your needs.

Comment: This will not work as the objects in OP's `allQuestions` array are not unique

Comment: @Frank well it's quite unsure what the OP really wants as the title is _"Vuejs - How to get all unique values in a array (remove duplicates) using v-for"_ where `Set` works just fine.

Comment: So how would you use Set to get the all objects within an array where all the values of a certain property of each object are unique . I'm honestly interested.

Comment: @Frank can you be more specific? "where all the values of a certain property of each object are unique" - isn't the requierment to find the unique ones, not all of them? Also please create a fiddle for testing.

Comment: It's exactly the same question as OP asked, considering the type of data he included. Ill make a fiddle

Comment: @Frank sorry for the late answer. I misunderstood the OP so yes, you are right - with only `Set` I doubt it's possible. However you can use reducer, filter, map,... to achieve that the OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to execute a **reducer** function on each item of the array, then merge the individual matches into the existing object with [assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). This merging process takes care of removing (or actually replacing) duplicate items.

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      allQuestions: [
        { id: '123', date: '14' },
        { id: '456', date: '2' },
        { id: '933', date: '2' },
        { id: '789', date: '7' },
        { id: '220', date: '14' }
      ]}
  },

  computed: {
    uniqueQuestions() {
      return this.allQuestions.reduce((seed, current) => {
        return Object.assign(seed, {
          [current.date]: current
        });
      }, {});
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="question in uniqueQuestions" :key="question.date">
    <button v-for="date in question.date">
    {{date}}
  </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although I'm not very sure with how you wanted the format of `question.date` to be like. In your example, you had it as string but I don't get why you would `v-for` the individual dates as char?

Answer (score 0):

You can use computed to display an array of all your questions sorted by date.

Comment: any other solution ?